# Get store ID by code

Tags: magento2, module, store-view

I get the category by calling the method from the repository:

```
$category = $this->_categoryRepository->get($id);
```

But I have multiple Store views, one for each language. I saw that the get method takes the store ID as second parameter. The problem is I only have the store view code. How can I get the category details by store code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Magento 2's dependency injection system. It means in your block class in __construct() method, inject Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface class as an object. Then you'll be able to get store view id. You need to do something like the following in your block class:

```
protected $storeManager;    

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,        
    array $data = []
)
{        
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;        
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

/**
 * Get store identifier
 *
 * @return  int
 */
public function getStoreId()
{
    return $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
}
```

If your current block class is `Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View`, then you'd need to use di.xml to extend your own module's block class to this class. More information on extending classes in Magento 2 is [here](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/overriding-classes-magento-2/)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code-

```
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface'); 
$storeid = $storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId();
$storecode = $storeManager->getStore()->getCode();
```